# Google Apps Script convert HTML to PDF not working anymore

Tags: html, pdf

Last year I used this code in Google Apps Script with no error. Today it's not working anymore. The error shows "Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed". Thanks for your help.

```
function testToPDF() {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1QHlMXx_IFWe90u4fLcprRWp");
  var html = "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
           + "<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "text/html", "text");
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
  
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");
  return pdfFile.getUrl();

}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the full text output of the error messages.

Comment: Hi @MarkStewart That's the full text with the line error shows on "const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");"